# Metapost: scale a picture

Tags: diagrams, metapost, scale

If I define a `picture`, how can I scale the picture by a scale factor? For example, if the scale factor is 5, then the target will be as 5 times as the size of the defined `picture`. The scale factor could be less than 1. The `picture` could be complex. It is something like `zoom in` or `zoom out` the defined picture. I am sorry I can't give a minimum code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `<picture> scaled <numeric>`. Taking an example from the Metapost manual:

```
beginfig(22);
path a, b, aa, ab;
a = fullcircle scaled 2cm;
b = a shifted (0,1cm);
aa = halfcircle scaled 2cm;
ab = buildcycle(aa, b);
picture pa, pb;
pa = thelabel(btex $A$ etex, (0,-.25cm));
pa := pa scaled 2;
pb = thelabel(btex $B$ etex, (0,1.5cm));
fill a withcolor .7white;
fill b withcolor .7white;
fill ab withcolor .4white;
unfill bbox pa;
draw pa;
unfill bbox pb;
draw pb;
label.lft(btex $U$ etex, (-1cm,.5cm));
draw bbox currentpicture;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Comment: My mistake is `draw pa scaled 5cm`. The scale factor should be `5` for my example. Thank you @ egreg